# No type or protocol named wkextensiondelegate

Tags: objective-c, watchos-2

i am going to update my existing project from IOS 7.0 to 9.1 with watch app extension through
File -> New -> Target -> Watch kit app.

it will added watch app extension in to main bundle with some files and watch storyboard.

my problem is when i run watch app it gives me error `"No type or protocol named wkextensiondelegate"`

see in my screenshot
[image]

i have added watchkit.framework to project -> Target -> build phase -> Link Binary With Libraries.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your xcode should be upgraded to the latest version. and download it below

https://developer.apple.com/download/